# ARIA how to announce when a dialog disappears

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria

Say that i have the following dialog:

```
<div class="loader" role="dialog" aria-label="Loading"> </div>
```

Now with Javascript i add and remove this element from the screen.

I am currently using `NVDA` as a screenreader and it reads it correctly however it doesn't let the user know when it is removed

is there a special attribute I can add to it?

Comment: Can you add some context? What are you trying to load? And where are you loading it into? Maybe ARIA live regions (specifically `aria-relevant`) offers what you're looking for? -- The idea would be to announce the availability of new information rather than announcing something disappeared.

Comment: @Bjorn Picture a page where i need to load either the full content or parts of the content on a page. then I create a dialog box popping up saying "Loading" the above code is just an example but here it doesn't state that it is closed

Comment: Ah I see. I think aria live regions offer what you're looking for: `<div class="here-goes-my-content-after-its-loaded" aria-live="polite" aria-busy="true">...</div>`. Then, when the content is loaded, you can set `aria-busy="false"`. [More info](https://dockyard.com/blog/2020/03/02/accessible-loading-indicatorswith-no-extra-elements)